# Plotting a 3D solid sphere in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a solid sphere in matlab and hence i trid the following code

```
for radius = 0:0.1:10
theta = linspace(0,2*pi);
phi = linspace(0,pi/2);
[theta,phi] = meshgrid(theta,phi);
[xs,ys,zs] = sph2cart(theta,phi,radius);
surf(xs,ys,zs);
end
```

But I still only get the surface of the outer most sphere.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In what sense you mean "solid sphere"? To see the internal spheres make them transparent or you will really see only the outermost one.

Comment: If u plot my code you can see that the bottom is open and and from below you can say that there is only one surface.

Comment: Thanks Pawel.That worked.Completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

As can be made out from the comments, the code to plot a solid half sphere would be:

```
hold on
for radius = 0:0.1:10
theta = linspace(0,2*pi);
phi = linspace(0,pi/2);
[theta,phi] = meshgrid(theta,phi);
[xs,ys,zs] = sph2cart(theta,phi,radius);
surf(xs,ys,zs);
end
```

For a full sphere one would also be interested in

```
surf(xs,ys,-zs);
```

Answer (score 0):

One quicker way that worked for me is:

```
phi = linspace(0, 2*pi);
```